# Allow Download From Shared Ubuntu Folder

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, shared-folders

I know that you can do the below commands to share a folder across the WAN:

1. `cd /home/user/FolderToShare`
2. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
3. Navigate to share by IP Address:8000
4. Terminate the server by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Now question is - is there a way using this method (or a different method) to allow a user who access this share to download files from the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (and I could be wrong as I still consider myself a newer Linux user) that if you want to allow the "Download" ability, you would need to use a service such as Filezilla or VSFTP.

Or, I just looked into this further, you can use `wget` on a windows machine by following this tutorial [WGET Tutorial](http://noahcoad.com/post/614/using-wget-on-windows) then you can use command prompt commands in windows to transfer over one file or the whole directory whichever you are after.  For a single file it would be something like this

```
wget http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8000/funnypic.jpg
```

For an entire directory it would be something like this

```
wget -r --no-parent http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:800/
```